# Update all git project in current directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have all my git project in the current directory

- tox
- Python-pattern
- Click
- ...

How to update all with `git pull` using make ?

Answer (score 0):

A) Add a target that contains a shell loop over all subdirectories and execute git pull in every subdirectory.
Mark the target as `.PHONY` so it is executed everytime it is called.